# How to implement group video chat using vLine API

Tags: api, video, chat, webrtc, vline

I am new to WebRTC and vLine API. I need to implement a Group Video Chat just like Google Hangout using vLine API and PHP. Please suggest if any example or solution available or how to go about it?

Thanks
Tanjum

Answer (score 1):

We have a PHP example on GitHub: https://github.com/vline/vline-php-example ([More examples available here](https://vline.com/developer/docs/examples)).

With the current API you can implement group chat with a mesh topology where each user establishes a connection with the other users (using [`person.startMedia()`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Channel#startMedia) on each person you want to include in the conference). Due to both bandwidth and CPU, this won't scale well beyond four people or so.

We have a better conferencing solution in development (that won the [Best Conferencing Award](http://blog.vline.com/post/54686370853/vline-wins-audience-choice-and-best-conferencing-awards) at the WebRTC Expo), but it's currently only available to a select group of beta testers.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom. It will be great if I can get access to the new conferencing solution. :)